# MySql data to Microsoft Sql by using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a problem with my project by using Entity Framework. I have successfully established the connection between this two databases. I was thinking to actually copy the mysql data from the databases and insert to the microsoft sql. I am quite new to this entity framework, could anyone here kindly guide me how to do this? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Seems what you're looking is bulk copy between those 2 DBMS. Include any code that you're tried to insert bulk records from source DB to other DB.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the generation of Ids. The easiest and safest method would be to let the new DbContext generate the Ids as if the elements are added as new objects

Alas that would mean you'd have to read all elements from the old database and add them to the new one.

```
using (var oldDbContext = ...)
{
    using (var newDbContext = ...)
    {
         var oldItems = oldDbContext.OldTable.ToList();
         foreach (var oldItem in oldItems)
         {
             var newItem = converOldItem(newItem);
             // you need your Id to have default value (zero)!
             var addedNewItem = newDbcontext.NewTable.Add(newItem);
         }
         ...
         newDbContext.SaveChanges();
     }
}
```

You'll need the addedNewItem if you have one-to-many relationships. For instance if a Teacher has many Students, your Teacher won't have a `TeacherId` before the `SaveChanges`. Hence you can't assign the Id of the Teacher to the foreign key in Student. You'll have to:

```
var newStudentToAdd = ConvertFromOld(oldStudent);
newSturdentToAdd.Teacher = addedTeacher;
```

The disadvantage of this all is that there will be a lot data in memory and that the conversion process will be fairly slow. Advantage: really safe, and during conversion you can make (default) changes.

You can increase the speed by disabling the detection of changes in the destination DB, thus forcing everything to be saved, without checking whether the data is changed.

Because you are creating a new database, all data is added, and thus all data should be saved, thus you will not need Change detection: [DbContextConfiguration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.autodetectchangesenabled(v=vs.113).aspx)

```
newDbContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
```

Another mthod, much more dangerous, would be to reuse existing Ids. If you do this, you'll have to generate ids yourself for all items that will be added in future after the conversion process. Make sure that in future the generation of IDs is compatible with the method to generate IDs in the old database.

If you decide to generate your IDs yourself. Override `DbContext.SaveChanges1:

```
class NewDbContext : DbContext
{
    ...
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        GenerateIds();
        base.SaveChanges();            
    }

    private void GenerateIds()
    {
        foreach (var addedEntry in this.ChangeTracker.Entries
            .Where(entry => entry.State == EntityState.Added))
        {
            ((IID)addedEntity).Id = idGenerator.CreateId();
        }
    }
}
```

To do this, every Entry (every class that is in a DbSet with a primary key) should have an interface indicating the primary key, Something like this:

```
public interface IID
{
    int Id {get; set;}
}

public class Teacher : IID
{
     public int Id {get; set;}
     ...
}
public class Student : IID
{
     public int Id {get; set;}
     ...
}
```

The IdGenerator should create similar IDs as the IdGenerator of the old database. During conversion you want to use the Ids of the old database, so make sure that these Ids are not recreated